# Mysql Join Two Tables With Recycling

Tags: mysql, join

Suppose I have two tables:

```
zoo_tbl
name
------
dog
cat
monkey
lion
tiger
elephant
fish

palette_tbl
rgb
------
pink
yellow
green
```

I want to do a join on the two tables such that the rgb rows repeat in a cycle.

```
name       rgb
---------------------
dog        pink
cat        yellow
monkey     green
lion       pink
tiger      yellow
elephant   green
fish       pink
```

How should I build this query?  I have an idea to create a large temporary table with recurring rgb values before joining, but even if I do that, I would have to enumerate the zoo_tbl and the temporary table before doing a join.  There has to be a simpler/more direct way to do this...

Comment: Given that tables are stored unordered, how do you wish to determine which records from the first table get paired with which records from the second?  Or does it not matter?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with MySQL alone. Will it be okay if you accomplish this using PHP or something?

Comment: You can leave out the ordering or add it in (as an additional column) if it makes the query simpler - as long as the colors recycle in some orderly manner, it's ok.

Comment: I prefer to do it in MySQL if at all possible (as a view or a stored-proc) - that way it may be reused in other applications.  The idea is to have a table of palettes that will automagically recycle for me given a proper view/join to any table that I want to "color" with a palette.

Comment: @kfmfe04: Well, if there is an ordered column, one could join the tables `ON palette_tbl.id = zoo_tbl.id MOD 3` or similar.

Comment: @eggyal - that's getting closer.  I remember trying to enumerate rows in mysql - iirc, it was a bit of a pain.  I would have to enumerate both tables and have the palette rows repeat a proper number of times, somehow...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have `PRIMARY KEY` on column `id` of table `palette_tbl`, this would do the trick for you:

```
SELECT name,
       (SELECT rgb FROM palette_tbl WHERE id = @row_id) AS rgb,
       (@row_id:= IF(@row_id = @cnt, 1, @row_id + 1)) AS dummy_id
FROM zoo_tbl a, (SELECT @row_id:= 1, @cnt := (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM palette_tbl)) dummy;
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0dd48/2)

Comment: FANTASTIC, Omesh!  If no simpler answers come up in the next hour or two, I will accept this as the answer!  TY.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` or `SUM(1)` would be cleaner if I can be nitpicky :)

Comment: thanks to all! :) `@biziclop`: ya right, may be that's my old habit of using `COUNT(1)` as long time back somewhere I read that `COUNT(1)` is faster than `COUNT(*)` but that may be applicable for older versions of MySQL. `COUNT(*)` would be a better way for new versions and other RDBMS systems as well.